# "New Virtual Machine Role" option in Visual Studio

Tags: azure

I have installed Visual Studio and Azure SDK v1.3. 
All I am trying to do is follow the steps on this tutorial Task5 step 4
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg502180 .

The only one I can not see is "New Virtual Machine Role"
I am new to azure, does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on an e-mail sent to you by wacc@microsoft.com.

"After you have installed the Windows Azure Tools, please run this additional script to enable the VM Role features in the Visual Studio development environment: 32-bit or 64-bit."

Select your environment and run the script.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently in beta and you have to request access before you can access the feature.

1. Log into the Azure portal
2. On the left there is a folders labeled Beta Programs, click that.
3. You'll see a list of available betas. (VM Role should be here)
4. Select it and hit join "(or request, I can't remember the exact word)

Once approved (not sure how long it takes anymore, prob pretty quick) you'll have the VM Images folder and can follow that tutorial.